# Unable to upload file to jersey

Tags: java, ajax, jersey

While i am trying to upload file to jersey i am getting below exception kindly some help me to resolve.thanks

Html doc :-

```
    <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
        <input class="form-control" id="fileupload" type="file" name="uploadfile">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
        <button type="button" class="form-control btn-sm btn-primary" id="file-upload">upload</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
        <button type="button" class="form-control btn-sm btn-danger">cancel</button>
        </div>
        </div>

    <br>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped"
            role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0"
            aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 20%">
            <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Ajax :-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#fileupload").click(function() {
    $(this).change(function() {
        var filename = $(this).val();
        var ext = filename.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
        if(ext =='yaml'){
            console.log(this.files[0]);
        }else{
            alert("."+ext+" is not vaild file extension");
            $(this).val('');
        }
    });
});
$("#file-upload").click(function(){
    var file = $('input[name="uploadfile"').get(0).files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('uploadfile', file);
    $.ajax({
        url : 'http://localhost:8080/IDNS_Rule_Configuration/idns/idnsData/importYaml', //Server script to process data
        type : 'POST',
        data : formData,
        cache : false,
        contentType : 'multipart/form-data',
        dataType : 'application/x-yaml',
        processData : false,
        success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var userObj = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
            alert(userObj);
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);

        }
    });

});

});
```

Java code :-

```
  @POST
  @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  @Path("/importYaml")
  public void uploadFile(@FormDataParam("uploadfile") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                             @FormDataParam("uploadfile") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uploadedInputStream));) {
     /* int numLines = 0;*/
      String line;
      while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null ) {
        /*numLines++;*/
        System.out.println(line);
      }
     /* return Response.ok(Integer.toString(numLines), "text/plain").build();*/
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      throw new WebApplicationException(e);
    }
  }
```

Exception :-

```
 Jun 17, 2015 7:55:34 PM         com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse   mapMappableContainerException
 SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-   throwing to the HTTP container
 java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.unquoteMediaTypeParameters(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:227)
at      com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readMultiPart(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:154)
at    com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderServerSide.readMultiPart(MultiPartReaderServerSide.java:80)
at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:144)
at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:82)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:488)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:552)
at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.FormDataMultiPartDispatchProvider$FormDataInjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(FormDataMultiPartDispatchProvider.java:122)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$VoidOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:166)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Jun 17, 2015 7:55:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke

Request header :-

```
 Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
 Request         URL:http://localhost:8080/IDNS_Rule_Configuration/idns/idnsData/importYaml
 Request Method:POST
 Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
 Request Headersview parsed
 POST /IDNS_Rule_Configuration/idns/idnsData/importYaml HTTP/1.1
 Host: localhost:8080
 Connection: keep-alive
 Content-Length: 339
 Accept: */*
 Origin: http://localhost:8080
 X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36   (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/39.0.2171.65 Chrome/39.0.2171.65   Safari/537.36
 Content-Type: multipart/form-data
 Referer: http://localhost:8080/FileUploads/index.html
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
 Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
 Request Payload
 ------WebKitFormBoundary1slIgbjdv3v2wkyD
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadfile"; filename="hk.yaml"
 Content-Type: application/x-yaml


 ------WebKitFormBoundary1slIgbjdv3v2wkyD--
 Response Headersview source
 Connection:close
 Content-Language:en
 Content-Length:3813
 Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
 Date:Wed, 17 Jun 2015 14:34:03 GMT
 Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Comment: I havent read your complete question but AJAX cannot be used for file uploads.

Comment: I wish to know alternate options to upload file to jersey.

Comment: Replace Ajax code with an actual form submit if page reload/redirection is fine or use a hidden iframe if page reload/redirection is not desired.

Comment: @vinay can you please explain why can't i use ajax to upload file to jersey.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Jersey. Ajax file upload is possible with HTML5. It was not possible with previous versions for HTML. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try this may work for you

$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'http://localhost:8080/IDNS_Rule_Configuration/idns/idnsData/importYaml',
                    enctype: "multipart/form-data",
                    data: formData,
                    processData: false,  
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function (data) {
    //some success functions
    }
    });
```